Redirecting to a new domain with htaccess whilst preserving the path
I've searched every relevant answer I can see on SO to no avail. I'm trying to ensure that the path from a domain redirect is also sent over to the new domain. I have what I feel should be the answer, so was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on this as it's driving my crazy!
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exmaple.co.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exmaple.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.exmaple.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Successfully redirects .co.uk as expected but fails to send over the path. I've tried appending %{REQUEST_URI} too but nothing.
Any ideas out there please? Thanks in advance!

This should work absolutely fine; the syntax is the absolute "usual", and https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=d6b60fff-7db8-4c0e-bf8d-23852dee86a4 also confirms. Please go check what actually happens, by looking at the requests being made in your browser dev tools, network panel. Guessing the new domain itself is probably redirecting you to its root, for some reason yet t.b.d.

Thanks a lot @CBroe, that was where my thinking led me to. Good shout on the network tab, I'm trying to get hold of the Apache logs too, but no joy yet. Will check it out and thank you for being a sanity check!
